# Sending an encrypted mail with javamail using PGP

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle, pgp

I've an error when i try to encrypt a mail using PGP

The error:

```
**java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No provider configured for PGP**
at    net.suberic.crypto.EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.java:106)
at    tools.Encryption.encrypt(Encryption.java:29)
at    core.mails.HtmlSeriesUploadingMail.sendMail(HtmlSeriesUploadingMail.java:93)
at    core.services.MailService.run(MailService.java:71)
at    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I saw that i need some library in my classpath so here is my classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mail.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/wrapper.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mysql.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/pd4ml.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ini4j-0.5.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jdom-2.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/bcmail-jdk14-139.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/bcprov-jdk14-139.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javamail-crypto_060622.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ss_css2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/certpath-api-compat.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cryptix-message-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cryptix-openpgp-provider.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cryptix-pki-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/cryptix-jce-provider-2.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

And here's my code to encrypt:

```
   public MimeMessage encrypt(Session session, MimeMessage mimeMessage, InternetAddress recipient) throws Exception {
      // get the PGP EncryptionUtilities
      EncryptionUtils pgpUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.PGP);
      // load the PGP keystore from the given file.
      EncryptionKeyManager pgpKeyMgr = pgpUtils.createKeyManager();
      pgpKeyMgr.loadPublicKeystore(new FileInputStream(new File(SystemData.getWatchDogConfig() + "test.asc")), null);
      // get the PGP public key for encryption
      java.security.Key pgpKey = pgpKeyMgr.getPublicKey((String) pgpKeyMgr.publicKeyAliases().iterator().next());
      // encrypt the message
      return pgpUtils.encryptMessage(session, mimeMessage, pgpKey);
   }
```

I don't know what i should do... I begin with javamail and bouncycastle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception `NoSuchProviderException` is thrown by `EncryptionManager` when it cannot find the provider specified in `getEncryptionUtils`. The providers are loaded statically in  `EncryptionManager` class by retrieving them from the file `META-INF/javamail-crypto.providers`. So, in order for `EncryptionManager` to load PGP provider you will have to add a `javamail-crypto.providers` file into your `META-INF` folder with the following line:

```
protocol=PGP;class=net.suberic.crypto.PGPEncryptionUtils
```